# Source of the Chemical Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

I know that the chemical potential is the energy required to add another particle to the system but what is it's origin on the microscopic level? Take for example the case of the ideal Fermi gas, the Hamiltonian:
$$H=\sum_i \frac{p_i^2}{2m}-\mu \hat N$$
clearly the first term is the kinetic energy but what *interaction* is causing the energy associated with the second term?

Comment: It's not an interaction within the gas, it has to do with how the particle bath is set up.

Comment: I just realized there is a misconception here relating to the nature of the chemical potential. This makes the question ill posed - but I think the misconception is an interesting one. As such if there are no answers before tomorrow (UTC) I will post an answer explaining the misconception as I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a misconception in this question about the nature of the chemical potential.  Although the chemical potential is often described as 'the energy associated with adding a single particle' this is has to be interpreted with extreme care. In this saying 'energy' refers to the 'mean energy' and 'adding a single particle' refers to 'changing the mean particle number by one'.

The change in 'mean energy' is not due to any interaction but rather the statistical effect that changing the mean particle number changes which microscopic states are more likely then others.

That said the presence of the chemical potential in the Grand partition function is equivalent to that of an interaction which acts on all particles equally. But this interaction does not have any physical meaning.

Comment: I think this is wrong. In particular, in the simple Gibbs ensemble you wrote down above, the (thermal) average energy of adding a particle is larger than $-\mu$, because this new particle will also tend to have some momentum.

Comment: @RyanThorngren True but we assume (sorry I forgot to mention) that entropy and volume remain constant. In this case I believe the energy only changes by $\mu$.

Comment: Interesting. So in other words, the new energy added from the extra $p^2/2m$ is accounted for by a slowing of the other particles to keep the volume from growing?

Comment: @RyanThorngren I also don't think this is correct. The chemical potential is the change in _free energy_ upon adding a particle. The change in _mean (internal) energy_ is different, for example for a classical ideal gas it would be 3kT/2 (the average kinetic energy of the added particle).

Comment: @user8153 This again comes down to my previous comment. We need to be holding entropy and volume constant. All I am arguing is that the relation $dU=TdS-pdV+\mu d \left<N\right>$ in a Grand Canonical ensemble. The mean internal energy of an ideal gas does change by $3k_BT/2$ if you keep temperature constant - but this is not what I am saying we need to keep entropy and volume constant not temperature.

Comment: @RyanThorngren See my comment above.  Answering your question: Remember that the kinetic energy is the only energy in play here. Adding another particle will increase the energy by $\mu$ and this must come from a change in the mean kinetic energy of the particles. I think your comment is correct. To keep the volume and the entropy constant, the pressure and temperature (which is related to kinetic energy) must change accordingly.